# How to use an cell value as PHP POST request with onClick action when click on a table row?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table with multiple lines, each line has a unique ID which i.e. is in row cell nr. 1 and is coming from a mySQL DB.

I want to click on that line and open a new .php file, this works with JS and onClick.

I want to handover the value from that cell into the new opened .php and use it in order to query against the DB, but not sure how.

Below is my snippet, which wouldn't work since I can't connect to mySQL and PHP.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-responsive table-hover" style="height: 150px; margin-top:2em;" id="CampaignTable">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <th>Campaign ID</th>
      <th>Campaign Code</th>
      <th>Campaign Description</th>
      <th>Campaign Start</th>
      <th>Campaign End</th>
      <th>Campaign Manager</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($campaign as $row){?>
    <tr onclick="location.href='campaign_detail.php';">
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[0]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_CODE]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_DESCRIPTION]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_START]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_END]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_MANAGER]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_STATUS]";?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the var you need in a querystring variable inside the "onclick" event (campaign_detail.php?ID=), like this:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-responsive table-hover" style="height: 150px; margin-top:2em;" id="CampaignTable">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <th>Campaign ID</th>
      <th>Campaign Code</th>
      <th>Campaign Description</th>
      <th>Campaign Start</th>
      <th>Campaign End</th>
      <th>Campaign Manager</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($campaign as $row){?>
    <tr onclick="location.href='campaign_detail.php?ID=<?php echo "$row[0]";?>';">
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[0]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_CODE]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_DESCRIPTION]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_START]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_END]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_MANAGER]";?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$row[CAMPAIGN_STATUS]";?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, this works, but it shows ID=121241. I want only the value.

Comment: In campaign_detail.php you can retrieve the ID parameter.

Comment: I removed **ID=** and now i get only the number. Can I built this into an SELECT query?

Comment: Thats actually what you need. Store the "ID" request parameter into something you can use in a SELECT statement or whatever you need :D

Comment: Fragment of "campaign_detail.php" should have: <?php
$idInYourDatabase = $_GET["ID"];
$sqlSelectStatememnt = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM campaign WHERE ID = " . $idInYourDatabase;
?>

Comment: alright,.. this looks good, but one more thing. The query is in another .php which i have as include. Somehow, i can't hand over the  $_GET["ID"] into the second .php.